# Concern about RDP

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a LAN set up at my apartment with a couple of PCs in the LAN network.

Say if I want to connect to computer B via RDP but a user is already actively using that computer. If I log in to computer B via RDP will that user get logged out? Or will he still have active control of the computer as well as I do?
PS: there is only one user account on that computer if that makes any difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is a windows client OS (like XP/Vista/7/8/8.1/10) computer that you are connecting to, you will take control of their computer and their session will go in to the background and they will see a locked screen, and that you are logged in. They can simply log back in to their own session, which will disconnect you. It's like the switch users process, none of their programs close, they just can't interact with them until they log back in.

This is one way MS makes money from businesses, selling windows server that can run remote desktop services (RDS) along with Windows and RDS client access licenses (CALs).

Edit: Scott has pointed out that since they are using the same user account, the other session won't go in to the background, it will simply be taken over, and the other person will either see a lock screen or be disconnected from their RDP session. Thanks Scott.

Comment: One small correction, the OP mentioned that the Login at the console session and the login for the RDP session will be the same user account so in this special case the session does not go in to the background but instead gets taken over by the RDP user. This only happens when you are logging in with the same user, had it been a different user it would be exactly as you described it.

Comment: Thanks! I need a small clarification though, will the actual user know that the PC is being accessed by RDP since he's not getting logged out? Is there like a notification or something?

Comment: @keklord the other user will be kicked out and will see the login screen when the person RDPs in.

Comment: There is a message, though I've forgotten its exact wording. I do not think it explicitly states that someone else has taken their session with RDP though. However for the person sitting at the console, that is the only likely thing that will cause it to happen. When someone steals your RDP session then also get a fairly basic message about you being disconnected, that is roughly the same message as when the connection drops out, except you get it straight away and it doesn't try and auto reconnect.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Oh yes I got confused there for a second. So if I log in via the same user account the actual user will get logged out. Thanks once more!

Comment: no, not logged out, but disconnected. all their programs continue to run. they just can't see them any more.

Comment: @BeowulfNode42 Yea you're right. It's like switching accounts not logging out.

Comment: @BeowulfNode42 one more thing, if there were more than 1 user account, if I to connect myself to the second account will the user that is actively using the PC on the first account know that I'm connected?

Comment: On a server OS (Anything with "server" in the os name), no, on a client OS (XP/Vista/7/8/8.1/10), yes. They get kicked out exactly the same way as if it was the same user account, however instead of the session getting taken over it is just suspended. The only way to not kick someone off of the computer is to pay for a server version of the OS.

Comment: @keklord yes, the reaction the person sees on the console (first account) will be disconnected just the same, the only difference will be that the lock screen will display both users are logged in if you use a 2nd account for the rdp.

Comment: @BeowulfNode42 and Scott

really appreciate your help guys now I understand what's what completely. Thank you!

Comment: @ScottChamberlain if you are buying a Windows Server OS to use RDS then don't forget to by the Windows and RDS CALs as well for each user or device that is going to be using it, apart from the 2 included administrative sessions.